# Turning sun into water

Tags: water, hydrogen

I don't know if this question belongs here or on physics stackexchange, but I believe it leans more towards this site.

A friend of mine had a strange but funny shower thought. He said:

> "What would happen if we bring one atom of oxygen for every two atoms of hydrogen to the sun, would that turn it into water?

Now, there are some hurdles, I know, but let's bend the rules a bit and suppose we could overcome the immense heat and radiation on sun's corona, and we brought the oxygen and hydrogen together, would that actually happen? What if the sun collided with a huge concentration of oxygen without it decomposing the oxygen molecules?

Again, it's crazy, I know, but would the sun turn into water?

Comment: Even if water forms it will get decomposed due to the high temperature of the sun.

Comment: Not enough oxygen on Earth to make a dent ... the sun is too big.

Comment: It does not lean towards chemistry, but astronomical speculation. Most likely outcome would probably be a really weird supernova.

Comment: Why not to ask about water stability at temperatures and P such as those at the various sun layers? As it is not a chemistry question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a speculation question whose response would use astronomical principles, if any.

Answer (score 1):

in the sun hydrogen is in the plasma state, which makes it impossible to form bonds (because in the plasma state electrons are separated from the nucleus)

not to mention the heat alone would easily break the bonds between hydrogen and oxygen if you brought water to the sun

Comment: Interestingly enough, water has been [observed](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/268/5214/1155?ijkey=cfbf7af3962d8b30ce76f01adc39fd6f88229992&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha) very close to the sun via rotational transitions (at excitation halfway to dissociation).